# SHA-512 library for PHP

Tags: php, sha2

I am searching for any crypto library that provides SHA-512 hash. Googling around I found some but SHA-512 is absent.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

If you are using PHP >= 5.3, the function [`openssl_digest`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-digest.php) should do the trick :

```
echo openssl_digest('glop', 'sha512');
```

gives me this output *(splitted in two lines to get better readibility)* :

```
416b1861951170e1f6eb6543b0dd3d4f1994ce8da7cd82061513d3ddd1dd81111
f4ada5caf6421f1d17425c6f29bdb4a95cf84df9eda4164f5a762acbb490a68
```

*(And you can use [`openssl_get_md_methods`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-get-md-methods.php) to get the list of available digest methods)*

And with PHP 5.1 or 5.2, you have the [`hash`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php) function :

```
echo hash('sha512', 'glop');
```

gives me the same output *(splitted, too)* :

```
416b1861951170e1f6eb6543b0dd3d4f1994ce8da7cd82061513d3ddd1dd81111
f4ada5caf6421f1d17425c6f29bdb4a95cf84df9eda4164f5a762acbb490a68
```

And, here, to know the list of available digest methods, you can use [`hash_algos`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hash-algos.php)

Comment: what is the difference between `openssl_digest` and `hash` in php >= 5.3?

Comment: -1 for not explaining why `openssl_digest` should be preferred over `hash`.

Comment: well can anyone explain if and why to use openssl_digest instead of hash?

Comment: They're the same. Also, check out this question for a good read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8952807/openssl-digest-vs-hash-vs-hash-hmac-difference-between-salt-hmac

Answer (score 16):

In PHP 5 >= 5.1.2, PECL hash >= 1.1:

```
hash('sha512', someStr);
```

See [hash()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php) for more information.
To see all hash algorithms available to you, try:

```
print_r(hash_algos());
```