# SHA512 in php - how?

Tags: php, codeigniter, sha

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SHA-512 library for PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1966154/sha-512-library-for-php)

I see the has() is only upto sha1. How to implement SHA512 properly with PHP, using codeignitor. Do i need an external library or is there built-in support for this? If external any suggestions on something open/free?

Thanks.

Comment: That question does not have a definitative answer just 1 suggestion which does not have any documentation on the function so i assume it is not fully supported.

Comment: Look again. Both functions are documented in the PHP manual. That should be affirmative enough. If you have a PHP setup where it is compiled out, there's nothing we can do about it.

Answer (score 1):

See https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hash-algos.php:

```
print_r(hash_algos());
```

That should give you SHA512.

Comment: Is this full proof like intended for this purpose or a hack way to get it?