# How to automatically generate salt for crypt method with blowfish

Tags: php, passwords, blowfish, crypt

I have just started learning PHP and I want to create a website with a login for my final year university project. I've read that blowfish is the best method for hashing in a number of places like here: [openssl_digest vs hash vs hash_hmac? Difference between SALT & HMAC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8952807/openssl-digest-vs-hash-vs-hash-hmac-difference-between-salt-hmac/11195855#11195855)

Everywhere I read about the crypt method includes a string like `$2y$07$usesomesillystringforsalt$` My main question is: how do I randomly generate this? I've read in places that time stamps and mt_rand() are not secure.

Also I've heard AES is the preferred technology recently but from what I can see it seems pretty tricky to implement in PHP! Is blowfish still an acceptable method to secure stored passwords?

Comment: Its not randomly generated its `$algo$cost$salt$` where salt is its perfectly safe to use microtime affixed with your domain name sha1'nd `substr(salt,0,21)` as anymore then 21 chars will be dropped. Perhaps something I made early will interest you [php-pdo-secure-login-script-example](https://code.google.com/p/php-pdo-secure-login-script-example/source/browse/branches/index.php)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A salt should be **unique** (for each password) and **unpredictable**. These two criterias are a bit difficult to fulfill with a deterministic computer, so the best thing you can do is, to use the random source of the operating system, to generate the salt.

Time stamps, as well as the [`mt_rand()`](//php.net/mt_rand) function, are not ideal, because one can argue that they are predictable. At least an attacker can narrow down (and therefore precalculate) the possible combinations for a certain period. While this may not have a big impact in practice, why not do the best you can?

Since PHP 5.3 you can safely use the [`mcrypt_create_iv()`](//php.net/mcrypt_create_iv) function to read from the random source, then you will have to encode the binary string to the allowed alphabet. This is a [possible implementation](http://www.martinstoeckli.ch/php/php.html#bcrypt).

PHP 5.5 will have it's own functions [`password_hash()`](//php.net/password_hash) and [`password_verify()`](//php.net/password_verify) ready, to simplify this task. There is also a [compatibility pack](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/password_hash) for PHP 5.3/5.4 available, downloadable at [password_compat](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

Answer (score 6):

For PHP version 5.3.7 or higher I belive this is the best:

```
$blowfish_salt = "$2y$10$".bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(22));
```

For PHP version 5.5 or higher just use the new `password_hash()` [function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) with automatic salt creation.

Comment: Beware guys, bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(22)) will return 44 characters.

For php blowfish, you need bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(11))

Answer (score 3):

Blowfish is still acceptable, and preferred over fast-hashing methods.

The point of a salt is to prevent precomputed table attacks. As long as you have a non-trivial salt, like the microtime, you have thwarted any precomputed tables that didn't happen to use that exact salt.

Comment: So would something along the lines of `$password = crypt($_POST[passward], '$2y$07$'.microtime());` be OK? Thanks for your help